# Reading one line of file into 2 variables in an object

Tags: c++, file, io

I'm going to try to be more descriptive this time, I've been doing research but can't seem to get it figure it out. I've got a class called Time that looks like this:

```
      class Time{

private:
    int minutes;
    int hours;
public:
    Time();
    Time(int h, int m);
    void addMin(int m);
    void addHour(int h);
    void setTime(int m, int h);
    void reset(int h=0, int =0);
    Time sum(const Time &t) const; //Add one time to another time.
    Time sum(int m) const;
    Time operator*(double other) const;
    void show() const;
};
```

I have a file that looks like this:

```
90 1 3.0
1 1 100.0
2 34 5.1
```

Where the first number in each line is `times[i].hours`, the second number is `times[i].minutes`, and the third value is a double to be stored in `math[i]`. Since the variables are private, I need to call a 'setTimeHours(int h)' and `setTimeMinutes(int m)` and I'm not sure how to do that. This is what I have.

```
        int number_of_lines = 0;
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(inputFile, line)){
            ++number_of_lines;
        }
        Time times[number_of_lines];
        double math[number_of_lines];
        std::string input;
        for(int loop=0;loop<number_of_lines;loop++){
            std::getline(inputFile, input);
            stid::istringstream(input) >> times[i].minutes >> times[i].hours >> math[i];
        }
```

The line I need help with is:

```
      stid::istringstream(input) >> times[i].setTimeMinutes(//what goes here?) >> times[i].setTimeHours(//what goes here?) >> math[i];
```

If, of course that'll even work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an input operator for `Time` and the input line would become

```
if (!(std::istringstream(input) >> std::skipws >> time[i])) {
    // report input error
 }
```

The funny `std::skipws` is needed to get a non-`const` reference to a stream (`std::istream&`) from the temporary `std::istringstream` which can only be bound to a `const&` (this works because the used input operator happens to be a member of `std::istream` and returns a `std::istream&`).

You'd just implement an input operator for you `Time` class, e.g.:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Time& time) {
    int value;
    if (in >> value) {
        time.setTimeMinutes(value);
    }
    return in;
}
```

Probably the input operator looks a bit more complicated than this but the basic idea stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since `minutes` and `hours` variables are private (which is definitely a good idea), replacing this line

```
stid::istringstream(input) >> times[i].minutes >> times[i].hours >> math[i];
```

with three lines

```
int hh, mm;
stid::istringstream(input) >> hh >> mm >> math[i];
times[i] = Time(hh, mm);
```

should work.

Another solution would be making an operator `>>` for reading a `Time`, like this:

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &is, Time &t) { 
    int hh, mm;
    is >> hh >> mm;
    t = Time(hh, mm);
    return is; 
}
```

then you would be able to do reading in one line - like this:

```
stid::istringstream(input) >> times[i] >> math[i];
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! I was trying to do it in one line, but this will serve its purpose just the same! Will accept in a few minutes!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read into temporary objects first:

```
int m;
int h;
std::istringstream(input) >> h >> m;
times[i].setTimeMinutes(h,m);
```

Your alternative may be to create another class or structure for the time and have an overloaded operator>> for the class/struct.